# Android - access the public key of its own in app runtime? Which the key-pair was used to sign the apk

Tags: android

How to get that base64 public key through Android API?

Comment: Are you not talking about the PRIVATE key?

Answer (score 5):

To get your public certificate you need to ise `PackageManager` in your code:

```
PackageInfo packageInfo = null;

try {
   packageInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 
                                           PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);

   Signature[] signatures = packageInfo.signatures;
   byte[] cert = signatures[0].toByteArray();
   InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(cert);

   CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509");
   X509Certificate c = (X509Certificate)cf.generateCertificate(input);

   PublicKey key = c.getPublicKey();

   ...   

} catch ( Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marcin, how do you use the public key to generate a rfc style cert?  I would like to compare the one from java api and the one exported by keytool, or just any method for me to double check.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The public key is stored in the META-INF/CERT.RSA inside the apk.

Comment: Thanks Mach, anyway to get it through Android API?  The question wasn't clear enough.